# Convert a 3D Matlab .fig to a rotatable 3D PDF

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, 3d

I'm trying to convert a 3D MATLAB plot to a rotatable PDF file (so the figure can be spun around and interacted with without MATLAB software for illustration purposes).

I have used this function https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25383-matlab-mesh-to-pdf-with-3d-interactive-object#feedbacks but can only get this working for surfaces (as its inputs are points, faces and face colour).

Does anyone know any methods of doing this? Or any other similar ways that involve being able to interact with a MATLAB figure in 3D from different software?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know this was possible at all, that's pretty cool. People are going to say this is the wrong forum for this question. Maybe Stackoverflow is a better fit.

Comment: I am afraid this question is outside the scope of this site. I also don't know any way to do that. Maybe you can google it. Like @littleO says stackoverflow might be better site for the question.